# Python Opening UTF-16 file read each byte

Tags: python, hex, utf-16

I am attempting to parse a file that I believe is UTF-16 encoded (the file magic is 0xFEFF), and I can open the file just as I want with:

```
 f = open(file, 'rb')
```

But when for example I do

```
print f.read(40)
```

it prints the actual unicode strings of the file where I would like to access the hexadecimal data and read that byte-by-byte. This may be a stupid question but I haven't been able to find out how to do this.

Also, as a follow up question. Once I get this working, I would like to parse the file looking for a specific set of bytes, in this case:

```
0x00 00 00 43 00 00 00
```

And after that pattern is found, begin parsing an entry. What's the best way to accomplish this? I was thinking about using a generator to walk through each byte, and once this pattern shows up, yield the bytes until the next instance of that pattern? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

EDIT: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: which version of python ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned - 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't you just be able to do this

```
string = 'string'
>>> hex(ord(string[1]))
'0x74'

hexString = ''
with open(filename) as f:
    while True:
    #char = f.read(1)
    chars = f.read(40)
    hexString += ''.join(hex(ord(char) for char in chars)
    if not chars:
       break
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works for one byte at a time (which is what I asked). As a follow up, is there any way to do similar to f.read(40) but have it return the hexadecimal values instead of Unicode characters?

Comment: Are you asking to read 40 characters at a time?  Should be fine.  I don't think you can 'read' it in as hexadecimal I am not exactly sure of the language here but if it is not hexadecimal in source then you have to convert it before you can then access the hex.  I don't know enough but I do not believe Python converts an ascii file (or any other kind of file) into hex when it reads it in.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys - this has been helpful for sure. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string of hexadecimal, you can pass it through [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    raw = f.read(40)
    hexadecimal = binascii.hexlify(raw)
    print(hexadecimal)
```

(This also works without modification on Python 3)

If you need the numerical value of each byte, you can call [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) on each element, or equivalently, [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) the function over the string:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    raw = f.read(40)
    byte_list = map(ord, raw)
    print byte_list
```

(This doesn't work on Python 3, but on 3.x, you can just iterate over `raw` directly)

Comment: This is extremely useful and actually more what I needed (I guess I wasn't really sure what I needed at first). Anyway, one follow up question, once I have the hex string I would like to iterate over each byte (2 characters) rather than each letter of the string - is there a way to easily do this?

Comment: If you want to iterate over each byte, it may be simpler to use the second option instead of the first.  But the magic incantation to iterate "two at a time" is `for first, second in zip(thing[::2], thing[1::2])`, assuming `thing` is of even length, which it is in this case.